# spring security remember me authentication

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security, remember-me

I have the mechanism to save cookies at the client-side. But when I was trying to implement remember-me using spring security I came upon this tutorial :

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/remember-me.html#remember-me-persistent-token

but here everything is abstract and no examples are given.. 
Can someone tell me how can I use the interfaces mentioned in this tutorial in my application where I need to implement persistent cookies... And kindly tell me what do I need to define in my security.xml file?

I am authenticating my user against RESTful services..

Answer (score 2):

The official documentation is not abstract. Turning on remember-me with Spring Security is very simple (I suppose that Spring Security already configured and users are stored in DB):

1 Turn on remeber-me in the conf :

```
<http>
    ...
    <remember-me data-source-ref="yourDataSource"/>
</http>
```

2 Create corresponding table in the database:

```
create table persistent_logins (username varchar(64) not null, series varchar(64) primary key, token varchar(64) not null, last_used timestamp not null)
```

3 Add corresponding checkbox to your login form:

```
<input id="rememeberMe" type="checkbox" name="_spring_security_remember_me">
```

In a case of REST you need to adjust third step according to your authentication scenrio.

Comment: I am new to spring security.. so I don't know how to configure it.. means what all I should include in the configuration like u said I should use <http> </http>.. but what all should I include in it.. and what all be there in security.xml

Comment: It will be better to correct the tittle of your question. Just start reading the doc from this point: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-web-xml. I can't say more, because everything depends on what do you have in your project. If something looks unclear for you then just post another more precise question. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. What I am trying to do is to implement the algorithm mentioned in the this link :
http://jaspan.com/improved_persistent_login_cookie_best_practice
for this I have an encrypted password and the database schema to support it... now I want to configure auto-login feature. and the authentication feature against REST services using spring security.. As the various articles I went through had some reference that spring security have interfaces for these two functions and we just need to implement them

Comment: In Spring Security you can customize hashing algorithm and database schema. So may be you can reuse his remember-me implementation.